How to configure the domain under which an optained MS Entra ID token will be readable client-side?
We decided we want one of our endpoints to be secured with a JWT mechanism.
The authentication is done via Microsoft Identity Platform with Microsoft Entra ID.
(It's the first time I integrate such a system and have no prior experience regarding JWT in general and in particular none with the whole MS Azure Authentication world.)
Now I have successfully integrated MSAL in my front-end and completed the sign-in process with a test user and am being correctly redirected to where I started the sign-in journey.
But I can't find the obtained Entra ID token in localStorage (where it should be according to my msalConfig).
I suspect that is because the token is stored under a different domain and thus I can't read it.
But I need to read it so I can send it as a bearer token to the endpoint as was intended.
Yes, I read the documentation (but not ALL of it), but am quite woozy from all the new terminology. So maybe this has to do with the audience that keeps popping up in the docs?
Between claims, scopes, audience, authority, tenants, clientId, etc. I am a bit lost I have to admit.
This is my msalConfig and my loginRequest
export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: globals.meta.config.MSAL_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: 'https://galactus.some-example-authority.com/',
    redirectUri: 'https://example.org/pages/galactus-login',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
}

export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: [],
}


Could you confirm whether your requirement is to get bearer token using msal react?

I'm not forced to use msal-react and could probably use purely msal-browser but it seemed a good choice because my visual parts are react-based.

@Sridevi I have not had the opportunity yet to try out and apply your answer and give it the attention that it deserves. My product owner put the Entra-ID integration on the back-burner for now and prioritised other features higher.

Any update on this?

Initially, I registered one application and below API permissions in it:

In Authentication tab, I added redirect URI as http://localhost:3000 in Single-page application platform:

Enabled public-client flows option like this:

In my case, I used below code files and got tokens with signed-in user details calling MS Graph API successfully like this:
authConfig.js:
// src/authConfig.js
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "appId", 
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000", // Redirect URI registered in Azure AD
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", 
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
};

export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read", "openid"], // Scopes for MS Graph API or custom API
};

App.js:
// src/App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { msalConfig, loginRequest } from "./authConfig";
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import axios from "axios"; 

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const App = () => {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("");
  const [idToken, setIdToken] = useState(""); 
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null); 
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

  // Initialize MSAL on app load
  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeMSAL = async () => {
      try {
        await msalInstance.initialize(); 
        console.log("MSAL initialized successfully");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("MSAL initialization failed: ", error);
      }
    };

    initializeMSAL();
  }, []);

  const loginAndGetToken = async () => {
    try {
      const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
      console.log("Login successful!", loginResponse);

      // Set the active account after successful login
      msalInstance.setActiveAccount(loginResponse.account);

      // Access tokens and ID token
      const newAccessToken = loginResponse.accessToken;
      const newIdToken = loginResponse.idToken; // Get the ID token

      setAccessToken(newAccessToken);
      setIdToken(newIdToken); 
      setUserName(loginResponse.account.name); 
      
      // Call the Graph API to fetch user profile info
      await callGraphAPI(newAccessToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login failed: ", error);
      alert(`Login failed: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };

  const callGraphAPI = async (token) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
        },
      });
      console.log("Graph API Response:", response.data);
      setUserProfile(response.data); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Graph API call failed:", error);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    msalInstance.logoutPopup(); 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>MSAL Login</h1>
      {!accessToken ? ( 
        <button onClick={loginAndGetToken}>Login</button>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>Logged in as: {userName}</h2> {/* Display user's name */}
          <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
      )}
      {accessToken && (
        <div>
          <h2>Access Token:</h2>
          <p>{accessToken}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      {idToken && (
        <div>
          <h2>ID Token:</h2>
          <p>{idToken}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      {userProfile && (
        <div>
          <h2>User Profile:</h2>
          <p><strong>Name:</strong> {userProfile.displayName}</p>
          <p><strong>Email:</strong> {userProfile.mail || userProfile.userPrincipalName}</p>
          <p><strong>Job Title:</strong> {userProfile.jobTitle}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

Output:

You can also decode above access token by pasting it in jwt.ms website and check claims like aud, scp to validate it:

If you exposed any API with custom scopes, make sure to use scopes parameter value as api://appId/scopename while getting token.

